# Manage transaction with spring-data and DynamoDb

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I'm newer with **DynamoDb**, and I have as information that Today, AWS are making DynamoDB with native support for transactions. I use spring-data in order to do operation into dynamoDb. But `@Transactional` doesn't work because when I add `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation spring ask me to add bean of type '`org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager`' as bellow, but I didn't found any implementation of DataSourceTransactionManager for dynamoDb.

How Can I Manage Transaction with dynamoDb and Spring-data?

```
@Bean public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() { return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb) you'll see that the last code change was 3 years ago or so, so this project is not longer maintained. I also don't think a `DynamoDB` transaction is the same as a `Spring` Transaction. In `DynamoDB`, this means that all updates to all tables will either fail or succeed. Whereas in `Spring`, there is an actual lock at the start of a `@Transactional`, which means if your code throws and exception, a rollback will occur. But you can't link the successful executing of your code to whether or not your `DynamoDB` update will fail or succeed.